# Python & fql: getting "Dami\u00e1n" instead of "Damián"

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, facebook-fql

I created a file containing a dictionary with data written in Spanish (i.e. *Damián*, etc.):

```
fileNameX.write(json.dumps(dictionaryX, indent=4))
```

The data come from some **fql** fetching operations, i.e.:

```
select name from user where uid in XXX
```

When I open the file, I find that, for instance, "Damián" looks like "Dami\u00e1n".
I've tried some options:

1. ensure_ascii=False:

   ```
   fileNameX.write(json.dumps(dictionaryX, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
   ```

   But I get an error (*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can´t encode character u'\xe1' in position XXX: ordinal not in range(128)*).
2. encode(encoding='latin-1):

   ```
   dictionaryX.append({
       'name': unicodeVar.encode(encoding='latin-1'),
        ...
        })
   ```

   But I get another error (*UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position XXX: invalid continuation byte*)

To sum up, I've tried several possibilities, but have less than a clue. I'm lost. Please, I need help. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this correct? By the JSON standard, non-ASCII characters can be represented using unicode escapes...so the file seems to contain the right data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options, and have stumbled upon something rather complicated that depends on your Python version and which **you absolutely must understand fully in order to write correct code**. Generally the approach taken in 3.x is stricter and a bit harder to work with, but it is much less likely that you will make a mistake or get yourself into a complicated situation. (Based on the exact symptoms you report, you seem to be using 2.x.)

`json.dumps` has different behaviour in 2.x and 3.x. In 2.x, it produces a `str`, which is a byte-string (unknown encoding). In 3.x, it still produces a `str`, but now `str` in 3.x is a proper Unicode string.

JSON is inherently a Unicode-supporting format, but it expects files to be in UTF-8 encoding. However, please understand that JSON *supports `\u` style escapes in strings*. When you read in this data, you will get the correct encoded string back. The reading code produces unicode objects (no matter whether you use 2.x or 3.x) when it reads strings out of the JSON.

> When I open the file, I find that, for instance, "Damián" looks like "Dami\u00e1n"

`á` cannot be represented in ASCII. It gets encoded as `\u00e1` by default, to avoid the other problems you had. This happens even in 3.x.

> ensure_ascii=False

This disables the previous encoding. In 2.x, it means you get a `unicode` object instead - a real Unicode object, preserving the original `á` character. In 3.x, it means that the character is not explicitly translated. But either way, `ensure_ascii=False` means that `json.dumps` *will give you a Unicode string*.

Unicode strings must be encoded to be written to a file. There is no such thing as "unicode data"; Unicode is an abstraction. In 2.x, this encoding is implicitly `'ascii'` when you feed a Unicode object to `file.write`; it was expecting a `str`. To get around this, you can use the `codecs` module, or explicitly encode as `'utf-8'` before writing. In 3.x, the encoding is set with the `encoding` keyword argument when you `open` the file (the default is again probably not what you want).

> encode(encoding='latin-1')

Here, you are encoding before producing the dictionary, so that you have a `str` object in your data. Now a problem occurs because when there are `str` objects in your data, *the JSON encoder* assumes, by default, that they represent Unicode strings *in UTF-8 encoding*. This can be changed, in 2.x, using the `encoding` keyword argument to `json.dumps`. (In 3.x, the encoder will simply refuse to serialize `bytes` objects, i.e. non-Unicode strings!)

---

However, if your goal is simply to get the data into the file directly, then *`json.dumps` is the wrong tool for you*. Have you wondered what that `s` in the name is for? It stands for "string"; this is the special case. The ordinary case, in fact, is writing directly to a file! (Instead of giving you a string and expecting you to write it yourself.) Which is what `json.dump` (no 's') does. Again, the JSON standard expects UTF-8 encoding, and again 2.x has an `encoding` keyword parameter that defaults to UTF-8 (you should leave this alone).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to open `fileNameX` **with a specific encoding** like `encoding='utf-8'` for example instead of using `open()`.

Also, `json.dump()`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still quite lost. I'd like to see "Damián" even though I used print json.dumps(dictionaryX, indent=4)

Comment: Let's say that I do this in a shell: >>>a = 'Dami\u00e1n'. Then I do >>>print a. I'd get: Dami\u00e1. What should I do to get Damián when I do >>>print whatever_modifying_a ?? Thanks!

Comment: Getting unicode strings to display properly in your shell is a completely separate issue! But in 2.x, that is not a Unicode string anyway. Try `a = u'Dami\u00e1n'`. Note that *`json` will translate these escapes for you when you `load` the JSON data.*

Answer (score 0):

Since the string has a `\u` inside it that means it's a Unicode string. The string is actually correct!  Your problem lies in displaying the string. If you `print` the string, Python's output encoding should print it in the proper encoding for your environment.

For example, this is what I get inside IDLE on Windows:

```
>>> print u'Dami\u00e1n'
Damián
```